# How to restore a fragment along with user-entered data

Tags: android, fragment

I have 3 fragments: where the user enters information in the first 2 i.e. A and B and the entered information is summarized in C. I am using a bundle to collect the info as well as backstack to help the user navigate back.

However, the main issue is that the information entered in fragments A and B are not saved once the user navigates away from them. So I am using the data in the bundle to pre-populate any pre-entered information should the user go back to fragments A or B.

This is really painful because I have all kinds of views. TextViews and TimePickers are fine but RadioButtons and CheckBoxes are really challenging.

I am fairly new to Android, been coding for about 4 months now. Is there an easy way to just save and restore a fragment (perhaps using fragment tag) that would persist the user-entered information as well? If so, please be descriptive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a singleton class to keep track of the information. After all, you only need one instance to keep track of such values between activities.

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation on file storage? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Answer (score 0):

> However, the main issue is that the information entered in fragments A and B are not saved once the user navigates away from them.

Easy way is to use `SharedPreferences`, save information that entered in fragment A and B into SharedPref as key-value, then retrieve them in fragment c and do your calculation.

> RadioButtons and CheckBoxes are really challenging.

Also save the status of each `RadioButtons` and `CheckBoxes` into SharedPref, then retrieve them and set there status.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those 3 fragments are housed by the same activity, you can use a shared ViewModel instance that represents the data relevant to those 3 fragments.

Take a look this link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

There's a section there on sharing data between fragments and shows an example of a custom ViewModel that's shared between two fragments.  The key thing there is

`model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);`

Note that it uses the enclosing Activity as the 'owner' of that SharedViewModel instance.  So two fragments housed by the same Activity will get the instance of that SharedViewModel and will be able to share data.  If you need to persist that data, then you can encapsulate that logic in the ViewModel or have that ViewModel delegate it to some DAO/Repository class.